# Problema con guardar datos en la BBDD

Tags: php, mysql

Por alguna razón no lo guarda, el $_POST lo recibe correctamente, pero en la funcion de guardado donde ejecuto el SQL no lo hace no entiendo el por que la funcion es esta

```
function guardar_dominio($input, $conn)
{

    if(isset($input['id']) && $input['id']!=""){

        $sql ="UPDATE dominios SET dominio='".utf8_decode($input['dominio']).
        "', renovacion='".utf8_decode($input['renovacion']).
        "', registrado='".utf8_decode($input['registrado']).
        "', estado= 1".
        ", status= 1".
        " WHERE id=".$input['id'];

        $conn->execute($sql);
    }else{
        var_dump($input);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dominios (dominio, renovacion, registrado, estado, status) VALUES ('"
        .$input['dominio']."', '"
        .$input['renovacion']."', '"
        .$input['registrado']."', "
        ."1, 1)";

        $conn->execute($sql);

        var_dump($sql);
    }
}
```

el calidad del codigo es algo antiguo dabido a que donde trabajo no saben trabajar mediante objetos pero bueno, el caso es que no entiendo la razon, hago el `vardump($sql)` y el INSERT es correcto alguien Sabria solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: @Oswuell no me da ninguno, eso es los extraño para mi solo pasa con esta  funcion debido a que tengo operaciones CRUD con otras tablas, lo que varia es los tados que reciben y el nombre de la tabla, no sé por que no funciona con esta.

Comment: Antes que nada creo que deberias de usar sentencias preparadas y poner el ejemplo de las buenas practicas en el lugar donde trabajas y en segunda ¿Que error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo puedes usar `execute` con sentencias preparadas, sí no quieres usar sentencias preparadas usa `query($query)` en lugar de `execute()`

más info sobre [query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)
más info sobre execute [execute](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Edito: Siempre es más recomendable hacerlo con una **query preparada** del método execute, que con el query directo, ya que el método query es susceptible a sql injection. lo mejor sería echarle un ojo a como prepara una sentencia con php.

Comment: Solucionado! aunque es la unica funcion que tengo con `query($query)` y funciona Gracias!

Comment: Quizá las otras sentencias las tengas ya con el `prepare` en alguna otra parte y no lo hayas notado, que ojo, siempre es más recomendable hacerlo de estar forma (con `prepare`) que con query directamente, esto para evitar algún sql injection

Comment: @juank deberías utilizar **prepare + execute** sin duda, no lo dejes solventado con _query_. Tal cuál lo tienes te puede dar muchos problemas (además de que no es seguro)

Comment: @Dibort Bueno, cuando termine las operaciones CRUD de esta tabla me pondré hacer los de preprare, no lo dejaré pasar Gracia a Todos :)

Comment: @juank para que te hagas una idea, [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/18216) tienes una explicación sobre el tema

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar el `execute` hay que hacer un `prepare` antes.

```
 $sql ="UPDATE dominios SET dominio='".utf8_decode($input['dominio']).
    "', renovacion='".utf8_decode($input['renovacion']).
    "', registrado='".utf8_decode($input['registrado']).
    "', estado= 1".
    ", status= 1".
    " WHERE id=".$input['id'];
 $prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $prepare->execute();
```

---

Como consejo, por el tema de inyeccion, yo no crearia la sentencia directamente si no que la [prepararia](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

en este caso quedaria:

```
 $params = array(
   ':dominio' => utf8_decode($input['dominio']
   ':renovacion' => utf8_decode($input['renovacion']),
   ':registrado' => utf8_decode($input['registrado']),
   ':id' => $input['id']
 ) 
 $sql ="UPDATE dominios 
           SET dominio= :dominio,
               renovacion=:renovacion,
               registrado=:registrado,
               estado= 1,
               status= 1,
        WHERE id=:id ";
 $prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $prepare->execute($params);
```

Puedes preparar de muchas maneras una sentencia, esta es una de ellas. Y le das mas seguridad a la actualización

Comment: Buen consejo! lo pondré ahora mismo aunque la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando es de uso privado. Gracias!